# ExtJs 4.2 : how renderer this combobox with store.query

Tags: extjs, store, extjs4.2

My application is in MVC.

I have a grid with columns, and one of these columns has a  with a renderer. This grid opens when the user clicks on an other grid.

When I load my application and I click to open this grid, this column (and the others after) don't load. But when I close and I re-open this grid, the columns are loaded.
I don't know where the problem is (moreover, this problem doesn't appear on the development server...)

I do a `console.log(Ext.getStore('sTypesJours'))` : I have some records

Then I do a `console.log(Ext.getStore('sTypesJours').query('uid', val, false, false, true))` : I have no records the first time, but after re-open it works...

This is the code of my grid:

```
Ext.define('KGest.view.grille.Modif', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'grillemodif',
    title: 'Elements déjà saisis',
    store: 'sGrilleModif',
    dockedItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            itemId: 'toptoolbarService',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'save-button-grillemodif',
                    text: 'Sauver les modifications',
                    iconCls: 'x-icon-save',
                    action: 'update',
                    dock: 'top',
                    scope: this
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    columnLines: true,
    viewConfig: {
        deferEmptyText: false,
        emptyText: 'Aucune donnée déjà saisie'
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
            listeners: {
                selectionchange: function(sm, selections) {
                    Ext.getCmp('validall-button-grillemodif').setDisabled(selections.length === 0);
                    Ext.getCmp('supprall-button-grillemodif').setDisabled(selections.length === 0);
                }
            },
            injectCheckbox: 7    // position de la colonne des checkbox
        });

        Ext.apply(me, {
            columns: [
                {
                    text: 'Journée',
                    dataIndex: 'journee',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    xtype: 'datecolumn',
                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                    width: 100,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        submitFormat: 'Y-m-d'
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Type de jour',
                    dataIndex: 'uid_types_saisies',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        store: Ext.create('KGest.store.sTypesJours'),
                        valueField: 'uid',
                        displayField: 'libelle',
                        typeAhead: true,
                        queryMode: 'remote',
                        emptyText: 'Sélectionnez un type de jour',
                        listeners: {
                            beforequery: function(queryEvent, eOpts) {
                                var tabFilter = new Array();
                                tabFilter[0] = {"property": "uid_salaries", "value": Ext.getCmp('uid_salaries').getValue()};
                                queryEvent.combo.store.proxy.extraParams.filter = JSON.stringify(tabFilter);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    renderer: function(val) {
                        if (val > 0) {
                            var srvStore = Ext.getStore('sTypesJours');
                            detail = srvStore.query('uid', val, false, false, true);
                            sortie = detail.getAt(0).data.code;
                        }
                        return sortie;
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: '1/2<br/>jour',
                    dataIndex: 'demi_jour',
                    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                    width: 50
                }
            ]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Best I can offer (6 months after question asked) is this:

timing is everything,  a field 'renderer' formats the cell-data at onload() time - meanwhile, instantiating and retrieving data to the store within the renderer function (when store-array is not-yet populated) returns undefined, by the time the next grid-load occurs, voila, there's the populated store, you get results from the query..
Probably solved this long ago, but load the store (autoload: true) or instantiate 'store' outside scope of grid-definition (before layout/renderer's are invoked)